Firebase Dynamic Link Redirects to App Store on Flutter iOS Even Though the App is Installed
Context:
I'm working on a Flutter app where Firebase Dynamic Links should open the app directly if it's installed. The setup is correct for Android and iOS, and the link works perfectly on Android. However, on iOS, the dynamic link always redirects to the App Store instead of opening the app, even though the app is already installed.
The Firebase Dynamic Link setup uses a custom domain (https://app.xxxxx.com/clearance), which correctly redirects to the underlying deep link (https://xxxxx.com/category/671). If the deep link (https://xxxxx.com/category/671) is clicked directly (from Safari or other apps), it opens the app without issues.
I'm using the app_links package to handle deep links inside the app and it works perfectly
Problem:
Whenever I try to open the dynamic link (https://app.xxxxxx.com/clearance) iOS always redirects to the App Store, even though the app is installed. This only happens on iOS, while Android opens the app directly as expected.
Info.plist Configuration:
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.xxxxx.custom</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>xxxxx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
    <string>applinks:xxxxx.com</string>
</array>

Things I've Tried:

Associated Domains Setup:
I’ve configured https://www.ksecret.com/en/.well-known/apple-app-site-association in the Info.plist and added the applinks entitlement for xxxxx.com.

Firebase Console Setup:
The custom domain is set up in Firebase, and the Apple App Site Association (AASA) file is verified.
Notes:

I am aware that Firebase Dynamic Links are deprecated, but we have time until August 2025 before migration is mandatory.

Question:
How can I ensure that the Firebase Dynamic Link opens the app directly on iOS instead of redirecting to the App Store if the app is already installed?


